# The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved (still)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Every time I try to build (doing a full Clean and then build afterward) I get this error message popping up under Eclipse's Problems section. The project itself also shows an error beside it.

I've tried everything contained in the other solutions to this exact same question:

1. Removing all libraries in project properties and re-adding them
2. Manually edit `project.properties` file, `.classpath` file, etc.
3. Performing full Clean and then build afterward

This stubborn error message won't go away. The problem is that the error doesn't tell me anything about what's messing up. The Location says "Unknown", and that's all I have to go on. No errors appear under any of the Build Path tabs. Everything looks fine.

What the heck is going on?!

**UPDATE:** Here's a screenshot of the 'Problems' tab:

[image: Problems tab]

Comment: Check your Android libraries as well. Maybe one (or more) can't be found. Also: could you post a screenshot of your Error Log as well?

Comment: @aardvarkk did you find out the solution? same issue here, I've working 4 hours straight to solve this....

Comment: @Dev I've got two suggestions. The first is to right click on the project and ask it to refresh. I think even though I was hitting F5 or something, it wasn't actually refreshing the project. But I think in this case I may have just switched to Android Studio? I find I always get these weird kinds of errors with Eclipse. Sorry I don't have anything more helpful to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart Eclipse. It works for me! 
You can also check with a new clean workspace if the above didn't work

Comment: I think sadly the solution did involve quitting Eclipse and restarting. Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

Look under 'Markers' tab, do you see any java build path issues there? Sometimes it complains about not having src/test/resources or other directories.

Comment: I only see the message shown in the original question. I'll attach a screenshot.